# Get key value from JSON that start with two braces

Tags: javascript, json

How can I get the value of final_balance in this JSON

```
{"1B22no5SKBuVRX3esHpgze5kAK5SzsA3B9":{"final_balance":1505100,"n_tx":1,"total_received":1505100}}
```

I tried a lot but still can't access to that key.

```
let url = 'https://blockchain.info/balance?active=1B22no5SKBuVRX3esHpgze5kAK5SzsA3B9&cors=true';

fetch(url)
.then(res => res.json())
.then((out) => {
  console.log('Checkout this JSON! ', out.final_balance);
})
```

Appreciate any help!

Comment: If you don't know the outer object's keys before hand (and how could you), you can use [Object.values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) or [Object.entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) to get the inner object.

Comment: @CharlesBamford output `0: {final_balance: 1505100, n_tx: 1, total_received: 1505100}
length: 1
__proto__: Array(0)` what should I do ?

Comment: `Object.values(out)[0].final_balance`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
JSON.parse('{"1B22no5SKBuVRX3esHpgze5kAK5SzsA3B9":{"final_balance":1505100,"n_tx":1,"total_received":1505100}}')["1B22no5SKBuVRX3esHpgze5kAK5SzsA3B9"].final_balance
```

**OR**

```
var data=JSON.parse('{"1B22no5SKBuVRX3esHpgze5kAK5SzsA3B9":{"final_balance":1505100,"n_tx":1,"total_received":1505100}}');
var final_balance=data["1B22no5SKBuVRX3esHpgze5kAK5SzsA3B9"].final_balance
```

Comment: Can you please edit your code so I can get the json data in a variable then parse it ?
like
`var jsonData = ...
`   `var balance = JSON.parse('jsonData')["1B22no5SKBuVRX3esHpgze5kAK5SzsA3B9"].final_balance
`

Comment: I have edited the code by placing a new variable named `data`.

Answer (score 1):

You can dig into the obj using Object.entries and loop through the index and indexes index to get the `'final_balance'`...

```js
let url = 'https://blockchain.info/balance?active=1B22no5SKBuVRX3esHpgze5kAK5SzsA3B9&cors=true';

fetch(url)
.then(res => res.json())
.then((out) => {
  Object.entries(out).forEach(index => index.forEach(key => key['final_balance'] !== undefined ? console.log(key['final_balance']):false))
})
```

Comment: That's why I love SO, Thank you so much for the explanition. I don't do a lot of work that need to understand how to get the JSON things, but, when I need to do it, I will get stuck, Anyways, Thank you that's helpful

Comment: How can I assign `  Object.entries(out).forEach(index => index.forEach(key => key['final_balance'] !== undefined ? console.log(key['final_balance']):false))
` to a global variable to use it in other functions ?